# How to permanently delete contact with API?

Tags: api, 4.6

I'm creating an automated test script. It creates a test contact, does some stuff, then cleans up after itself by deleting the contact.

However this still leaves the contact in the "Trash".

How can I either just delete the contact fully with one API call?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can pass the `skip_undelete` parameter to the API, ie.

```
$result = civicrm_api3('Contact', 'delete', array(
  'sequential' => 1,
  'id' => 9999999999999999999, // replace with your contact's Id.
  'skip_undelete' => 1,
));
```

Obviously a lot of care has to be taken over specifying the id to delete...

Comment: Hmmm. However when I try to run this in my CLI test code it says "could not delete contact". Separate question or quick comment reply?

Comment: CiviCRM on Drupal uses Drupal's user_access() for checking permissions; `global $user; $user = user_load(1);` does the trick if you can't use `drush -u 1 scr <yourscript>` for some reason.

Comment: Thanks, that worked.