# Can cv handle custom Wordpress installs?

Tags: testing, cv

A wordpress install I'm adding CiviCRM to is setup in a non-standard way, specifically:

```
docroot
\- civicrm.settings.php
\- wp-config.php
\- content/
|  \- plugins
|  | \- civicrm
|  \- uploads
|     \- civicrm
\- wp (wp codebase in here)
```

I've got CiviCRM working fine, but I can't get my tests to run that rely on booting CiviCRM from `cv php:boot`. Trying to run `CIVICRM_SETTINGS=civicrm.settings.php cv -vvv ...` from the docroot just silently dies. I'm using cv version `b3db22c`.

Comment: Does it have the same problem if `CIVICRM_SETTINGS` contains the full path?

Comment: 'fraid it makes no difference specifying the full path. And just to test, if I give a duff path it complains loudly in a big red box.

Comment: I'm not well versed in this, so I could be way off, but shouldn't you be running that command from inside the wp dir, perhaps even deeper, with a full path for the CiviCRM_Settings call?  Doesn't cv want to be inside the wp dir?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to the helpful comments, I conclude: Yes it can, with a bit of help.

### TL;DR

- you need to define `CIVICRM_CMSDIR` in your code
- you need set `CIVICRM_SETTINGS` as an environment var

### Longer version

As far as I can work out, `cv` sources `civicrm.settings.php` before it sources `wp-config.php`. So if, like me, you have config set in `civicrm.settings.php` that depends on constants defined in `wp-config.php` you'll have to find a solution for that (e.g. use `if (defined('...'))` or put them all in a separate file and `require_once(...)` it.)

Then you need something like this in your `civicrm.settings.php`:

```
define('CIVICRM_CMSDIR', __DIR__ . '/wp');
```

Basically CiviCRM is going to expect to find `wp-includes` inside that directory, so adjust as you need to.

You don't need to call `cv` from within any particular directory, according to my tests.

You need to set the environment variable `CIVICRM_SETTINGS` to point to the `civicrm.settings.php` file. This can be a relative or absolute path.

I was then able to get cv to run, e.g. to use the API. Now if only I could get my tests to run....!